# Status bar change color in simulated metrics swift ios

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to change status bar color through simulated metrics, however, when I pick my view controller and set status bar to light content, nothing changes. Should I do this in the code or am I doing something wrong by setting status bar color in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

AppDelegate:

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method

UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

If you show Particular ViewController use this below code,

Select the `ViewController` file, `viewDidLoad` method, use this code,

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

hope its helpful